# What does cpu-pinning mean in context of KVM hypervisor with multiple virtual machines

Tags: kvm-virtualization, affinity, pinning

I am looking at configuring a KVM hypervisor to have some virtual machines.

THe KVM hypervisor has 8 physical cores (16 with HyperThreading). I want to create 8 virtual machines on it but I am not able to understand what difference will cpu-pinning have on it.

What will be the difference when I pin each VM to a different core vs when I pin all the VMs to all the cores (by setting the affinity to cpu 0-15)

Will it have any performance benefits?

I guess I will have some caching benefits but will there be a difference if I want to run traffic to all the VMs?

Comment: Do you _really need_ to do CPU pinning?

Comment: I was trying to measure performance of httperf if my VM has the http server running. without pinning I was seeing the httperf using the full nic bandwidth. But with pinning I saw a drop in performance. I wanted to understand what difference did the pinning make

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CPU pinning ensures a VM will only get CPU time from a specific CPU or set of CPUs. Unless you have a very specific reason to pin, there usually is no need to do that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you can have a performance gain if you pin each VM to specific CPU cores, as well as restrict the hypervisor to one or two other cores.

That would allow your VM's to optimally benefit from the L1 and L2 caches which are CPU specific and they won't be bothered by interrupts from NIC's and storage controllers.

On the other hand I expect the hypervisor already makes an effort to mostly direct CPU events of the same virtual CPU to the same physical core and I doubt it would be a *significant performance gain* if you manually force something more strict.

The disadvantages of that are pretty obvious too, when you assign more cores to virtual guests than available physical cores are present it is unlikely your manual CPU pinning does a better job than the hypervisor. It will also be hell when you use live migrations.

Comment: I've seen performance drop on moderately loaded systems, when pinning was in use

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's your case, but it can help others.

CPU pinning can be really usefull in case your system has multiple NUMA Node.
Usually, it's multi socket systems.

Pinning core of a vm on only one cpu of the system avoid using memory from the other CPU, reducing latency and cpu cross talk.
In the same case, it's usefull if you do pcie passthrough, as the pcie lanes are only comming form one cpu.